# Android-Realm list with strict Model/View separation

Tags: android, realm

I've got a RecyclerView backed by a Realm `findAll()`.  I use a RealmChangeListener to notify the list about updates, and everything works remarkably well given the heavy use of the blunt instrument notifyDataSetChanged().

```
private RealmResults<Sale> allSales;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....

    // Update sales list whenever the AllSales result changes
    allSales = getRealm().where(Sale.class).findAll();
    allSalesListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Sale>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Sale> results) {
            saleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }};
    allSales.addChangeListener(allSalesListener);
    ....
```

However, I'd really like to have good MVVC structure, keeping all the Realm code in the ViewModel and out of my Fragments.  The Realm examples don't do this.  And probably for good reason -- I don't see an elegant way to notify the adapter appropriately of changes in the RealmResults.  Databinding isn't there yet; it doesn't seem to support backing a RecyclerView with an ObservableCollection... and even if it did, a RealmResult isn't an ObservableCollection.

At this point, I'm thinking that I need to create a "ListChangedListener" interface in my Fragment, and manually maintain a collection of listeners for every List property in my ViewModel.  But that seems like an awful lot of extra code just to maintain View/Model separation.

TLDR: I'm looking for an example of a Realm-backed ListView or RecyclerView with *no Realm code whatsoever* in the View code.  Or even just reassurance that my custom "listener" interface is a good path forward.

UPDATE: I had somehow overlooked the RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Realm library includes a RealmRecyclerViewAdapter base class, which I had somehow overlooked.  No matter how good your MVVC intentions, the Adapter can't really be divorced from the model implementation, so it may as well be one that's intended for it.

Anyhow, it is very clean and compact.  Do yourself a favour and [review the example](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.java).

Here's a minimalist working implementation, with Android Databinding used for the row fields to make the Adapter and ViewHolder even cleaner and simpler:

```
private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    // Called from your onCreateView(...)
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mainActivity));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(mainActivity, mainActivity.getDb().serialsRR));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}



public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Serial, MyRecyclerViewAdapter.SerialViewHolder> {

    private final ActivityMain activity;

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ActivityMain activity, OrderedRealmCollection<Serial> data) {
        super(activity, data, true);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public SerialViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.serial_row, parent, false);
        return new SerialViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SerialViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SerialRowBinding rowBinding = holder.getBinding();
        rowBinding.setSerial(getData().get(position));
    }

    class SerialViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener {
        @Getter SerialRowBinding binding;

        public SerialViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view);
        }
    }
}
```